# Why we use const array in a function, even the original array are not const?

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

I hope that these code  express my question more clearly.

```
double xxxx(const double* const array){
//...
}
int main(){
double* array = new double [5];
xxxx(array);
}
```

Is it actually create a new const array in the stack and heap by the input of the function?

Comment: You use it to indicate that you're not going to modify the array. This way, the function can be used with both const and non-const original arrays.

Comment: It doesn't create a new array.